# .Net c# application - Proper way to solve performance issues related to change tracking in Entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework

We have a Web MVC .NET application that uses the code first approach. Everything behaves normally when performing basic CRUD operations but our reports and long running tasks are taking forever to complete.

Most of our problematic cases can be resumed by the following 2 scenarios:

1. There is a task that iterates on 10,000+ items (using `sqlDataReader`), makes a few
   changes and creates a copy for each of them.
2. We have reports that iterates on 100,000+ items (using `sqlDataReader`) to read some information and write to a file.

After realizing that the time required to process our tasks and reports grew exponentially (`O(n^2)`) with the number of items to process, we investigated further and found out the root of the problem: Change Tracking in Entity Framework.

Everything works fine if we disable `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` but every article we've read on the subject says we should avoid doing this whenever possible.

So here is my question: Is disabling `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` the only or the recommended way of solving those kind of problems? Is there any other cleaner solution? How would you approach this?

This is assuming we would follow all the recommendations stated in this series of articles: https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/

Here is a small code sample illustrating scenario 2 :

```
//SQL query to fetch 100,000+ items
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

//Use SqlDataReader to stream results
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    /*In the following loop, if we use SqlCommand instead of LINQ, it's fast and steady. 
      But as soon as we start using LINQ, each iteration takes exponentially more time 
      to complete - even if we are only making read operations. Unless we disable 
      AutoDetectChangesEnabled: then it's fast and steady.*/
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        /*Fetch additional information. I know this could be done with a join in the 
          original query but we have a lot of additional info to fetch and the query would 
          be too heavy (this is a simplified version of the code).*/
        Item item = db.Items.Where(x => x.OtherItem_Id == (int)reader["Id"]).FirstOrDefault();

        //Read properties
        prop1 = item.prop1;
        prop2 = item.prop2;
        prop3 = item.prop3;

        //Use those properties to add an entry to a csv file
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking a very broad question here,there is no one way to debug or solve the performance issue you are having, performance issues are always very challenging to fix and always a myriad of possible solutions

Comment: You may want to just say away from turning off AutoDetectChanges, as I think that might prevent EF from knowing which records are Dirty on SaveChanges, though I could be wrong, just taking a guess, haven't worked with EF in a while

Comment: It can be done properly (e.g. using the property API to update fields) but I do agree it's not something that should be disabled if possible. That's why I'm asking the community's opinion here. I'll post a sample so you can have a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently hard to answer your question without having a specific example. As Brian said in the comment section, they can have a myriad of possible solutions...

By example, one solution could be as simple as using AddRange once instead of adding entity every time you loop in your DataReader.

```
var listA = new List<A>();
while(dr.Read())
{
    var itemA = //...code...

    // ctx.Add(itemA); // DON'T do it...
    list.Add(itemA);
}

ctx.AddRange(listA);
```

The DetectChanges method will be called only once instead of X times.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

Another solution could be the same problem I recently received. Detecting Changes was taking over 1 hour for someone due to having a very complex and big model.

Instead to use SaveChanges, we simply suggested him to insert using BulkInsert from our library directly: [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/) which improved the performance by more than 50x times.

---

**EDIT: Answer sub-question**

> when AutoDetectChanges are enabled, it's slowing things down even for read operation

Some read method like find automatically call the DetectChanges, so yes, some read operation are also affected by the DetectChanges

```
public TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
{
  this.InternalContext.ObjectContext.AsyncMonitor.EnsureNotEntered();
  this.InternalContext.DetectChanges(false);
  // ...code
}
```

Comment: Weird thing is: when AutoDetectChanges are enabled, it's slowing things down even for read operations (we aren't modifying any values and are not calling any method that use DetectChanges). I'll try to paste a sample of the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially multiple ways you could improve performance, but as it has been said above, its hard to help with those type of issues as there could be other parts of the code impacting this that we just can't see.  With that said, here are a few ideas.

1 - Your EF LINQ query is in a self-described loop of 100,000 items.  That means you are going to issue 100,000 queries to your DB during this loop.  Depending on the `Items` table size and complexity, you could get all of those records into memory and then do your LINQ commands on an in-memory list.  This would cut your SQL queries by 99,999.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    //pull the entire table to an in-memory list.  
    var items = db.Items.ToList();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Item item = items.Where(x => x.OtherItem_Id == (int)reader["Id"]).FirstOrDefault();
        prop1 = item.prop1;
        prop2 = item.prop2;
        prop3 = item.prop3;
    }
}
```

2 - You can trigger the `NoTracking` directly in your query.  If this is truly readonly dataset, then you would not be in any danger as you are not calling `db.SaveChanges()`

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Item item = db.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.OtherItem_Id == (int)reader["Id"]).FirstOrDefault();

        prop1 = item.prop1;
        prop2 = item.prop2;
        prop3 = item.prop3;
    }
}
```